# how to find the return value from the map is empty

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

im trying to create a listview with a search query, i want to show a empty icon when the return element form the map function is empty can any help me to achive this

```
ListView(
          children: controller.todo.value.where((element) {
        if (controller.search.value != '') {
          return element.labels!
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(controller.search.value);
        }
        return true;
      }).map((todo) {

      //here i need to check whether it is null or nor
      
      return Text(todo.name)}).toList())
```

Comment: you want show icon instead of empty list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    List<Widget> children =
        controller.todo.value.where((element) {
      if (controller.search.value != '') {
        return element.labels!
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(controller.search.value);
      }
      return true;
    }).map((todo) {
      return Text(todo.name);
    }).toList();

    return children.isEmpty
        ? Center(
            child: Icon(Icons.warning),
          )
        : ListView(
            children: children,
          );
  },
),
```

Comment: its working only when the controller.todo is empy but in this case i need to find the filtered value from the map function is empty or not

Comment: you want to show icon when controller.search.value is empty? @VenkatCpr

Comment: nope ,need to show the return value from the map function

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @VenkatCpr